# UITextField inside UIStackView inside UIStackView inside UIScrollView not scrolling with keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a controller which creates the needed views programatically, the views are as follows:

1. header = UIStackView
2. body = UIScrollView
   2.1 body content = UIStackView vertical
3. footer = UIStackView

views 1, 2, 3 are added to the main view
view 2.1 is added to 2

The layout is fully working as is, the way the app works is that it gets a json object from the server, which contains a list of elements that need to be added to views 1, 2.1 and 3.

Views 1 and 3 need no scrolling.
View 2.1 contains elements that often overflow the screen thus the need for scrolling.

The elements to be added are of multiple types such as UIImage, UIButton, UITextView, UITextField...

All elements are fully adding to the layout and the scrolling continues to work without any problems except when I focus on a UITextField, as soon as I focus, the soft keyboard shows up, if I attempt scrolling it does but, as soon as I type any character, the scrollview jumps up, the scrollbar becomes very small and I can't scroll properly any more. When I loose the focus of the field and the soft keyboard is gone, the scroll problem continues.

Does anyone have any idea what maybe causing the problem?

Update:

I tried playing with the constraints.
The working version has the body content view with top and bottom anchors to the parent view (view 2).
Removing thos constraints and adding a width and height anchor causes the scrollview not to scroll any more.

Moreover, I tried manually setting the contentSize of the scrollview but that does not do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

For me, the problem was the height constraint, however leaving the constraint enabled when the keyboard is not showing caused the UIScrollView not to scroll, so I toggle the constraint on and off with the keyboard notification.

Here is what I ended up doing

Initialize the layout

```
let bodyWrap = UIStackView() //2 UIScrollView
let contentWrap = UIStackView() //2.1 body content
let bodyAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint? //I used this on keyboard displayed
contentWrap.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyWrap.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
contentWrap.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyWrap.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
/*
 * Add all needed subviews to contentWrap
 * Then...
 */
contentWrap.setNeedsLayout()
contentWrap.layoutIfNeeded()
bodyAnchor = contentWrap.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentWrap.frame.height)
```

Then when the keyboard is shown

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardShown(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardHidden(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardShown(notification: Notification){
    bodyAnchor!.isActive = true
}

@objc func keyboardHidden(notification: Notification) {
    bodyAnchor!.isActive = false
}
```